# Is RWS Article One Partners a scam?

Tags: rws

I joined Article one and submitted around 200 patents information and have seen that there are more qualified people submitting information which is better than mine.

The chances of me getting any money appears to be slim, but in the hope of earning some money I am submitting lot of useful information which included patents/literature/articles and books and at the end of the day, I am still at the bottom of the ladder with no money to earn.

All of the research I am doing for Article one is actually going waste as I get emails from them that my research is not at all useful. They accept a few responses as they call them and increase the submission limit which forces us to submit more responses in the hope of getting a prize. But after that again message comes that your responses are useless/not relevant.

Sometimes after accepting the response they say it is unacceptable after a few days. So I am confused that submitting such useful information is not productive and to submit as little as information as possible which they accept.

If they don't accept the first few responses as within scope, we should avoid submitting more important information as it only increases their free database which is being built on our responses.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do with RWS Article One? It isn’t clear to me.

Comment: In two of the studies both had a similar requirement and I submitted a common patent to both of them to check what the Reviewer would do. In one study he gave it a rating of "3" and in the same patent on another similar study he gave a lower rating of "2" although both requirements were similar and I had submitted a common patent in both.

Comment: A patent can be more or less relevant based on specific details so I can't question whether a particular ranking makes sense or not. Please look at my response to your comment below.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to [AOP Connect](https://app.articleonepartners.com/ip-research/studies/active). I have no experience with this site or business. It seems as though they are crowd sourcing technical research particularly with respect to invalidity. They have "gamified" so they only pay out to the best submissions. It looks legit to me, but as I said I've never dealt with them. I would say, it looks like they are looking for technical experts in very select fields. I think you are unlikely to get much out of posting information to requests you are not an expert at.  From what I can tell, the site rewards quality over quantity. Since it seems to not be working for you I would suggest giving up on it.

Comment: After submitting a patent they give a rating of "3", then they allow more submissions. But after we submit more submissions/responses, they give it a lower rating of "2" or below and our grade becomes poor. Then a message comes that your submissions are not good enough. So, I am selectively submitting submissions and waiting to see if they really pay any money or are just making a database out of the responses. After submitting 25 responses, the Reviewer says my responses are useless, but at the beginning they accept a few of them and allow more responses.

Comment: In general, patent examiners are very capable of finding other patents when they review a patent application. Thus pointing out patents is perhaps less likely to provide an invalidity basis than other, non-patent literature. I think you focusing on providing patents as your submissions is less likely to suit the needs of the website. In any case, I don't think I can help you any further.

Comment: I have provided both patent and non-patent literature but the chances of getting any money out of it is very slim. I already got zero money in four studies I participated in.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I have seen is that they force you to submit more and more documents by offering bonus submissions.

After collecting the bonus submissions, they generally don't pay. Also, they don't pay to people who submit 25 or more submissions on one study even if the majority of the submissions were accepted by them to be good.

I had 18/25 submissions good on several studies and they gave no money on those but encouraged to submit more documents in the name of bonus submissions which is a trick to fool people to send more documents to them.

The reviewer also behaves like real enemy and gets angry and if he is crossed with you, he will give bad rating to all your submissions without even looking at them.

Generally submit only one or two documents and if they get a rating of "2" best not to submit more documents as they will not pay you even if you were to submit dozens of documents because if you get "2" in the studies it means no money.

They have opposite scale of rating "3" is ranked higher than "2" and no one gets a "4" which is highest.